# Calling javascript function from a separate php script?

Tags: javascript, php

I have javascript function written within a "generate.php" script and I have "call.php" in a separate script. How do I add a button in "call.php"script that triggers a function in "generate.php"?

"generate.php": javascript; function called by 'save'

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");


$chart_data = '';

$db = new dbObj();
$connString =  $db->getConnstring();
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query = $connString->prepare("SELECT ID FROM Datas WHERE ID=?");
$query->bind_param('s',$id);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->get_result();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chart_data .= "{ ID:'".$row["ID"]."'},";

}
echo $chart_data;

$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> PHP & Mysql</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.1/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <button id="save">Download</button>
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">MySQL</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Data</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div id="bar-chart" data-colors="#29abe2,#ffc142,#1ab394, #FF0000, #FFFF00" ></div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$("#save").click(function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('bar-chart')).then(canvas => {
        var w = document.getElementById("bar-chart").offsetWidth;
        var h = document.getElementById("bar-chart").offsetHeight;

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);

        var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'pt', [w, h]);
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, w, h);
        doc.save('xkey.pdf');
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
})
</script>
```

"call.php";

```
<?php
include_once("generate.php");

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db01");
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datas WHERE ID LIKE '%" .$_POST["search"]."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<h4 align = "center">Search Result</h4>';
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table bordered">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>

                        <th>Generate</th>       
                    </tr>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>

                    <td><a href="generate.php?id='.$row["ID"].'" target="_blank"><button  id="gen" name="generate" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa"" aria-hidden="true"></i>Generate</button></a></td>      
                </tr>
            ';
    }
    echo $output;

}
else
{
    echo "Data not found";
}

?>
```

Comment: as the JS script in `generate.php` does not use any PHP output itself, better move it in separate JS file and include it with `<script>` tag into your `call.php`.

Comment: @mitkosoft it does but I have not added it since it would be an overflow of information.

Comment: I have added the complete script now.

Answer (score 0):

Your pos-PHP code must be located in same document. So either include it via `<script src="generate.php">` or via `<? require 'generate.php'; ?>`

Comment: This can work, but why include an entire file if only one small part of it is needed?

Comment: @El_Vanja Because that's how it works. You can move your JS code to simple `.js` file and include it without PHP part (if proper)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same functionality in separate scripts, you should extract your js function to a file. Don't forget to name it:

```
function giveItADescriptiveName() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('bar-chart')).then(canvas => {
         // etc
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
}
```

Then you can include that script in any file where you might need it:

```
<script src="path/to/where/you/saved/it/whatever-you-called-the-file.js"></script>
```

And ultimately, you pass your function as the handler:

```
<script>
$("#save").click(giveItADescriptiveName());
</script>
```

Comment: but why extract it to a separate file? There should be way to call the function right?

Comment: You can't call it unless you include it somehow. So it's either extraction to a separate file, or including the entire other php file. This is a cleaner solution.

Comment: okay so how do I call the <script> from call.php with a button? I mean from ```<td><a href = ...```

Comment: Just like you did with "save". Write a selector for your desired element and attach a click handler that calls it.